# What does TIME+ (cpu time, hundredth) in top mean?

Tags: linux, cpu, top

See the example below. Automount is showing 3019:57 in the TIME+ column.

```
Tasks: 241 total,   1 running, 240 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.7%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16435884k total, 15007668k used,  1428216k free,   454300k buffers
Swap: 33554424k total,      140k used, 33554284k free,  1915400k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
**27026 root      15   0  974m  12m 1616 S  3.3  0.1   3019:57 automount**
 4619 root      15   0  245m  24m 9444 S  2.0  0.1   3491:25 java
20515 root      15   0 15720 1532 1124 R  0.7  0.0   0:00.03 top
    1 root      15   0 10372  644  548 S  0.0  0.0   0:04.87 init
    2 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   2:49.80 migration/0
    3 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:20.90 ksoftirqd/0
    4 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0
    5 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   3:53.73 migration/1
    6 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:34.51 ksoftirqd/1
```

Does it mean it has spent an accumulated 3019 hours of CPU time?

Answer (score 24):

Haven't looked at the source code of `top`, but it seems like `3019:57` in column `TIME+` means 3019 minutes 57 seconds of accumulated CPU time.

- `999:00.00` means 999 minutes
- `1000:00` means a thousand minutes (no `.` separator at all)

I confirmed it on my system. I took an example process from `top` with `2529:38` then checked it with `ps -fp PID` which showed  `1-18:09:38`. The latter is one day and eighteen hours, which is approximately two and a half thousand minutes. Hence it equals the former.

Answer (score 2):

I find the meaning of `TIME+` through the `man top` command. It said the following in the `3. FIELDS / Columns` chapter:

> ```
>  29. TIME  --  CPU Time
>      Total CPU time the task has used since it started.  When Cumulative mode is On,  each  process  is  listed
>      with  the cpu time that it and its dead children have used.  You toggle Cumulative mode with `S', which is
>      both a command-line option and an interactive command.  See the `S'  interactive  command  for  additional
>      information regarding this mode.
>
>  30. TIME+  --  CPU Time, hundredths
>      The same as TIME, but reflecting more granularity through hundredths of a second.
> ```

When I let `top` display both the `TIME+` and `TIME` fields, I find the details as follows:

| TIME+ | TIME |
| --- | --- |
| `5432:01` means "5432 minutes and 1 second" | `90,32` means "90 hours and 32 minutes" (that is "5432 minutes") |
| `25:15.20` means "25 minutes, 15 seconds and 20% of 1 second" | `25:15` means "25 minutes and 15 seconds" |

Answer (score 1):

the TIME+ column in TOP command, is not in minutes, is in hundredths of a second. 
source: https://www.maketecheasier.com/linux-top-explained/

greetings

Comment: This is incorrect and meaningless.  The time column has a colon separating two values so saying it is any one unit makes no sense.  What the manual page (and your link) are saying is that the TIME+ column has a granularity of hundredths of a second.  The units are still minutes:seconds, you just get fractions of seconds as well after the decimal point.  These fractions of seconds have a granularity of hundredths of seconds, hence there are at most two digits after the decimal point.